# Signed texture negative value are clamped to zero

Tags: opengl, openscenegraph

I am trying to use a 3D signed texture for volume rendering. The problem is that all voxels whose values are negative are clamped to zero when accessed in the shader.
This is how I create the image and set the 3D texture:

```
char* volumeData = LoadVolume();
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Texture3D> volumeTexture = new osg::Texture3D;
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Image> volumeImage =new Image;    volumeImage->setImage(textureWidth,textureHeight,textureDepth,GL_LUMINANCE16,GL_LUMINANCE ,GL_SHORT,volumeData,Image::AllocationMode::USE_NEW_DELETE); 
volumeTexture->setImage(volumeImage);
```

I tried gDebugger to read the textels values' in the GPU memory and I confirmed that all negative voxels are clamped to zero.

Comment: `GL_LUMINANCE` is a normalized format; negative values aren't supported. Try one of the integer texture formats like `GL_R16I`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use GL_LUMINANCE, which is normalized. Use non-normalized texture formats. You can find them here
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format